# Minecraft 1.15.2 default resource pack to 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I am aware that some of the subfolders in the assets folder in 1.15.2 are named differently from 1.12.2, I did change "block" to "blocks" and "item" to "items", but it doesn't seem to work.

I looked everywhere and for the life of me, I can't find a single person who attempted to do this.

I am also aware that some blocks and items names have changed, but even for example diamond_ore which has the same name for both versions, it didn't change to 1.15.2 texture.

Please, if you can tell me what I did wrong, or link me to some kind of converter, that would be amazing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested edit! I will look more carefully for mistakes next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure it out, but I found someone on curseforge who backported it to 1.6 - 1.12 (name: Modernity) and so, I will be using their texture pack.